# Spring Framework rest services with React.js

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, rest

I want to make a React.js webapp which gets the data from Spring rest services. Whatever examples/tutorials I got, everybody uses Spring Boot, not Spring Framework. I want to build an app with Spring Framework, not Spring Boot.

So, my question: Does it make sense at all or everybody is using Spring Boot now unless they have a legacy app which was built when Spring Boot did not exist?

I want to build it as a war file, not as a java application as Sprint Boot does. I understand that I can package Spring Boot app into war, but I want to see if I can make a pure Spring Framework war file and use it.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't allow questions asking for off-site tutorials or examples. One of the reasons why is because those tutorials could disappear in the future.

Comment: I understand, I changed the question without asking for tutorials.

Comment: You should prefer Spring Boot.  It's using Spring, but adds things to make your life easier.  If you insist on just Spring, create Controller classes and deploy them.  Those are your REST services.

Comment: Don't see what a WAR and JEE server add, either. Executable JAR is the way to go.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does it make sense at all or everybody is using Spring Boot now unless they have a legacy app which was built when Spring Boot did not exist?**

I think it depends on priority like if you want to configure your application from scratch you can opt for spring framework and there are several companies they are still using spring framework for backend because of their complex application and manual configuration which gives them better control over the application.

**I want to build it as a war file, not as a java application as Sprint Boot does. I understand that I can package Spring Boot app into war, but I want to see if I can make a pure Spring Framework war file and use it.**

Although spring boot is often associated with jar deployments but still you can create a war file from spring boot if needed.